# Divide vector by interval so that smallest group has certain size

Tags: r, vector

Assume I got a vector a, like this:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- sort(abs(rnorm(500, mean = 1000, sd = 350)))
```

I want to find out the smallest size (or probably range, I'm not sure about the english word here, sorry) of that interval, if you cut the vector with, the smallest group will have e.g. 30 elements.

In this case the result would look like this:

```
cut(a, breaks = seq(0, max(a) + a[30], by = a[30]))
```

and `a[30]` (here 462.2426) would be the value I'm searching for. In this case it was easy to find it, because the vector is normally distributed and the value was very likely to be either `a[30]` or `max(a) - a[length(a) - 30]`. But how to find it in general?

---

In case someone is interested what this is good for: In variograms lag classes should contain at least 30 point pairs (approximate empirical value), but the more lag classes you got, the better your variogram will look (or in some rare cases the resulting plot point out of the lag class will only make your variogram interpretable). And the value I'm looking for will be passed as `width` argument to `gstat::variogram`.

---

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate, but I didn't find the other one then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I execute your first two commands and then

```
table(cut(a, breaks = seq(0, max(a) + a[30], by = a[30])))
```

I get the output

```
        (0,462]           (462,924]      (924,1.39e+03] (1.39e+03,1.85e+03] (1.85e+03,2.31e+03] (2.31e+03,2.77e+03] 
             30                 175                 226                  65                   3                   1
```

and hence `a[30]` does not seem to be the number that you are looking for, since there are two groups with less than 30 elements.

Maybe you can think about your question and state it in a more precise way. One problem that I see is that in many cases the last group will have only few elements (as in your example), so maybe you should treat the last group as special and not demand that it should have at least 30 elements. If you exclude the first and last group of the 'more than 30' condition, then

```
intLength <- max(a[k:n] - a[1:(n-k+1)])
startingPoint <- a[which.max(a[k:n] - a[1:(n-k+1)])]
breakPoints1 <- seq(startingPoint-intLength, min(a)-intLength, by = -intLength)
breakPoints2 <- seq(startingPoint, max(a)+intLength, by = intLength)
cut(a, breaks = c(breakPoints1,breakPoints2))
```

(where `n = 500`, `k = 31`) might help you.

Comment: You're right, a[30] seems not be the value I'm looking for. I think I confused something with executing the definition of `a` several times, while `seed(1)` of course is only applied the first time. So in this case the searched value is `val <- max(a) - a[length(a) - 30]` and `table(cut(a, breaks = seq(max(a), min(a) - val, by = -val)))` gives: `(5.37,781]      (781,1.56e+03] (1.56e+03,2.33e+03] 
                124                 346                  30`, but however, I don't think it makes a too big difference for the understandability of my question.

Comment: I would not exclude the first group aswell as the last group from the 'more than 30' condition, but rather only the last group. I can't see if it makes any difference, but I thought of computing those groups as above and then cutting off the extremely high values (in my example with the variogram, in `gstat::variogram` there is an option to pair points only to a certain maximum distance (argument `cutoff`), but the pairs with the small distances (here the small values) are crucial to the execution of the variogram.

Comment: `table(cut(a, breaks = c(breakPoints1,breakPoints2)))` gives me  
(7.85,783]      (783,1.56e+03] (1.56e+03,2.33e+03] (2.33e+03,3.11e+03]  
127                 344                  29                   0  
and `table(cut(a, breaks = c(breakPoints1,breakPoints2), right = F))`  
[7.85,783)      [783,1.56e+03) [1.56e+03,2.33e+03) [2.33e+03,3.11e+03)  
127                 343                  29                   1  
so that one group always has only 29 values in it. I would mange this as follwos:  
breakPoints2 <- seq(startingPoint-tiny, max(a)+intLength+tiny*n/k, by = intLength+tiny)

Comment: I dunno who supervised my edit of your answer and rejected it, but here is what I did: corrected a typo: `startingPoint <- a[which.max(a[k:n] - a[1:(n-k+1)]-1)]` and since `-1` is critical due to the fact that not all values have a difference > 1 I introduced a variable, small enough to not cause this problems: `tiny <- min(a[2:n] - a[1:(n-1)])/ (n/k)` and changed the definition of `startingPoint` again: `startingPoint <- a[which.max(a[k:n] - a[1:(n-k+1)]-tiny)]`. I also use exactly this `tiny` in another comment of mine.

Comment: I really like your approach with the differences! That's genius! (and I will of course accept it, as soon as someone peer reviewed my edits and you edited your definition of `brakPoints2` (or `breakPoints1`), so that every group indeed has 30 elements. I suggested a solution in another comment). Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Still added a loop to better meet the needs of `gstat::variogram` (`k, tiny, intLength` as before, `n <- length(a)`):
`breakPoints <- seq(0, (max(a)/intLength)*intLength, by = intLength)
table(cut(a, breaks = c(breakPoints)))

cutoff <- floor(max(a)/intLength)*intLength
a <- a[which(a < cutoff)]

while(any(table(cut(a, breaks = c(breakPoints))) < 30)){
  n <- length(a)
  intLength <- max(a[k:n] - a[1:(n-k+1)])
  breakPoints <- seq(0, (max(a)/intLength)*intLength, by = intLength)
}`
So that `gstat::variogram` looks like:
`variogram(object, locations, cutoff = cutoff, width = intLength, ...)`

Comment: I corrected the mistake you found and changed the suggested value of `k` from 30 to 31 so that each 'inside' group will have at least 30 elements.

Comment: In order to see why the code above might lead to 'border' groups with less than 30 elements, run the code with `a <- c(0:80, seq(81,141,by = 2), 142:529)` instead of a randomly generated `a`.

Comment: There were still 2 bugs in my code, but besides that, I'm convinced it works. The code produces a possibly small border group only on the upper tail and there it simply cuts it off (which in terms of variogram is defining a maximum distance up to which point pairs should be made). The upper code always makes the largest allowed value a multiple of the range of a group, which I now doubt is necessary. However, here the bugfixes: `breakPoints <- seq(0, max(a) + LagRange, by = LagRange)` and `while(any(table(cut(a, breaks = breakPoints)) < k & table(cut(a, breaks = breakPoints)) > 0)){}`